# How to split data that is separated by headers into different chunks?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, numpy

I have a set of data that is split every couple of lines by a header. I would like to read this file with pandas and split it into multiple arrays for each part after a new header. The number of rows in between the headers is not necessarily equal, so ideally it would detect a header, skip it and start a new data frame, or would write the index of that row into a list or something so that I can slice it up later.

I tried something like this:

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', skiprows=list_of_skipped_rows)
```

But that is inconvenient because I have to create list_of_skipped_rows 
manually.

The data looks something like this:

```
spin 1: WF(Fe3_3d-2) -> WF(Fe3_3d-2) at relative 
T=      0.00000      0.00000      0.00000  hop=            -0.458880333440493 +i*              0.000000000000000
T=      0.00000      7.27841      0.00000  hop=            -0.035603658911014 +i*             -0.000000000000000
T=     14.55682      7.27841      0.00000  hop=             0.002829331916122 +i*              0.000000000000000
spin 1: WF(Fe3_3d-2) -> WF(Fe3_3d-1) at relative 
T=      0.00000      7.27841      0.00000  hop=            -0.032224030850531 +i*             -0.000000000000001
T=      0.00000     -7.27841      0.00000  hop=             0.032224030850531 +i*              0.000000000000001
T=     -7.27841      0.00000      0.00000  hop=            -0.042422160597321 +i*              0.000000000000001
T=      7.27841      0.00000      0.00000  hop=             0.042422160597321 +i*             -0.000000000000001
T=     -7.27841     -7.27841      0.00000  hop=            -0.038244803420008 +i*              0.000000000000001
T=     -7.27841      7.27841      0.00000  hop=             0.001458007120899 +i*              0.000000000000000
T=      7.27841      7.27841      0.00000  hop=             0.038244803420008 +i*             -0.000000000000001
spin 1: WF(Fe3_3d-2) -> WF(Fe3_3d+0) at relative 
T=      0.00000      0.00000      0.00000  hop=             0.241909440386978 +i*             -0.000000000000001
T=      0.00000      7.27841      0.00000  hop=            -0.032644583985555 +i*             -0.000000000000001
T=      0.00000     -7.27841      0.00000  hop=            -0.032644583985555 +i*             -0.000000000000001
T=     -7.27841      0.00000      0.00000  hop=             0.055254423473069 +i*             -0.000000000000001
T=      7.27841      0.00000      0.00000  hop=             0.055254423473069 +i*             -0.000000000000001
T=     -7.27841     -7.27841      0.00000  hop=            -0.028268235984415 +i*             -0.000000000000001
T=     14.55682      7.27841      0.00000  hop=             0.005804248461754 +i*             -0.000000000000001
spin 1: WF(Fe3_3d-2) -> WF(Fe3_3d+1) at relative 
T=      0.00000      7.27841      0.00000  hop=            -0.032224030850531 +i*             -0.000000000000001
T=      0.00000     -7.27841      0.00000  hop=             0.032224030850531 +i*              0.000000000000001
T=     -7.27841      0.00000      0.00000  hop=             0.042422160597321 +i*             -0.000000000000001
.....................
```

Comment: You could read the file with ordinary Python functions, and identify and count the header lines.  Then use that to guide the `csv` formatted read.  `pd.read_csv` has lots of parameters, but they can't account for all variations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, this sounds a little difficult to do with the functionality provided by `pd.read_csv` out of the box. The way that I might do this is to manually read in the file line by line, and use a regex to detect when I hit a header row, since they all seem to be formatted a particular way. Upon hitting a header row, I'd create a new DataFrame and add rows one by one. Here's a possibility:

```
list_of_dataframes = []
current_df = pd.DataFrame() # you may want to pass in column names here
with open("data.csv") as file:
    for line in file:
        if isheader(line): # define some function that checks if it's a header. If so, skip line; create new dataframe.
            list_of_dataframes.append(current_df)
            current_df = pd.DataFrame()
            continue
        tokens = line.split(",") # or whatever delimiter you're using
        current_df = current_df.append(pd.Series(tokens, index=current_df.columns), ignore_index=True)
list_of_dataframes.append(current_df)
```